# How many $2$-star in a complete graph?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, trees

A $2$-star is a tree with exactly two internal nodes.
How many $2$-star in a complete graph are there?

In my opinion $${n\choose 2} \left(2^n-2\right),$$ 
my teacher said $${n\choose 2}2^{n-1}.$$

Comment: In your _opinion_? This is not a matter of opinion; it is either right or wrong. Do you have an _argument_ for your answer?

Comment: I have made some fast calculations, this is why I have chosen the word opinion. I have not written a proof. BTW, I just realised that what I proposed is wrong, now I will try again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get neither of these but instead
$$ \binom n2 (3^{n-2}-2^{n-1}+1) $$
First a factor of $\binom n2$ for how to choose the two internal nodes.

Once they are chosen, each of the $n-2$ remaining nodes can be neighbors of either one of the internal nodes, or the other, or of neither -- except that we need to exclude choices where one of the nodes have no neighbors at all (and so is not internal).

---

If you're asking how many of the 2-stars use *all* of the nodes in the complete graph, a similar analysis leads to
$$ \binom n2 (2^{n-2}-2) $$
which again matches neither of the proposals.

Comment: Thank you, I meant this second answer and I was just editing my "proposal" with the formula you gave, but you have been faster than me!